# Navigate to another viewController from slide menu? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I have slide tableViewMenu, but my navigation from clicked sell to another viewController doesn't work.
Here is my code from main view controller:

```
 @IBAction func menuButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let menuViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuViewController") as? MenuTableViewController else {
        return
    }
    menuViewController.didTapMenuType = { menuType in
        print(menuType)
        self.transitionToNew(menuType)
    }
    
    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    menuViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    present(menuViewController, animated: true)
}



func transitionToNew(_ menuType: MenuType){
    
    switch menuType {
    case .favourites:
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "favourites") as! FavouriteStationsTableViewController
        self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case .nightMode:
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
                appDelegate?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
           
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

and in MenuViewController is this code:

```
enum MenuType: Int {

case home
case favourites
case nightMode
```

}

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var didTapMenuType: ((MenuType) -> Void)?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let menuType = MenuType(rawValue: indexPath.row) else {
        return
    }
    
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        
        [weak self] in
        print("Dismissing: \(menuType)")
        self?.didTapMenuType?(menuType)
      }
}
```

When I try to navigate, the Menu View Controller just dismissed.

Comment: Difficult to help with a description of *"doesn't work"* -- Are you seeing the debug output from `print("Dismissing: \(menuType)")` and `print(menuType)`? If you set a breakpoint at `switch menuType` is the value of `menuType` what you expect it to be?

Comment: @DonMag  The problem is on Navigation, It doesn't go to another view controller

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and step through to confirm your code is flowing to the right place? Does the `. nightMode` selection work as expected?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, I set the break point, and step trough, it goes to "break". I'm new in swift and I don't know where to find the problem.

Comment: OK - if it skips over `case .favourites:` and `case .nightMode:` and goes to `default: break` then the value of `menuType` is not equal to `.favorites` or `.nightMode`. What is the value of `menuType` at the beginning of your `switch` block?

Comment: and, how are you defining `MenuType`? Is it an `enum`? Edit your question and include **that** code.

Comment: @DonMag Yes, there is an enum - Int. I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

In this enum:

```
enum MenuType: Int {

case home
case favourites
case nightMode

}
```

`.home` equals `0` (zero)

`.favourites` equals `1`

`.nightMode` equals `2`

You're setting:

```
`let menuType = MenuType(rawValue: indexPath.row)`
```

and you're probably tapping on the first row, which will be `0` (zero). So, you're setting `menuType` to `.home`.

Comment: so where is the problem with this?

Comment: @BetYx - are you selecting the first row in your "slide menu"?

Comment: I have three rows and when I select 0,1 or 2 is the same. Just dismissing and go back to home screen. How to set menuType to .favourites or .nightMode?

Comment: @BetYx - you need to answer my earlier questions... *"what is the debug output from `print("Dismissing: \(menuType)")` and `print(menuType)`?"* and *"what  is the value of `menuType` when you reach your `switch menuType` block?"*

Comment: there is output: Dismissing: home - home. I need when I click on second row to navigate to another viewController.

Comment: @BetYx - this is confusing... You're saying that regardless of whether you tap on "Home" or "Favourites" or "Night Mode" in your menu table view, `menuType` is being set to `.home`? That doesn't seem possible with the code you've posted. To give you any more help, you'll need to create a [mre] so I can run your code and see exactly what's happening.